# How do I set default time to a specified hour with TimePicker dialog?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-timepicker

I have a Fragment that launches a TimePicker dialog for the user to select a time of day.  I would like the default time of day that is shown when the dialog launches to be 4:00 PM.  The user can then select their own time thereafter.  I  have been trying setHour and setMinute but to no avail.

Below is partial code for the TimePicker that sets to the current time of day.  Please advise on how to modify to always show 4:00 PM when TimePicker dialog first launches.

```
...
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    minute = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    TimePickerDialog dialog = new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(),this,hour,minute,
            dialog.setTitle("Select...");

    return dialog;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the method

```
dialog.updateTime(int hour, int minute);
```

as shown in the [API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TimePickerDialog.html). Key point is that the hour is always in the 24h format. Alternatively the constructor also accepts the hour and minute as `int`s

```
    TimePickerDialog(Context context, 
        TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener listener, 
        int hourOfDay, int minute, boolean is24HourView)
```

for example set to 4:00 PM without 24h format:

```
TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, 16, 0, false);
```

Comment: I understand, I am trying now.

Comment: Ok "TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, 16, 0, false);" works perfectly.  Cheers to you, milez.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to create your calendar instance as below

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:ss");
        Date date = null;
        try {
            date = sdf.parse("04:00");
        } catch (ParseException e) {
        }
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.setTime(date);
      //create your timepickerdialog instance here
```

Comment: Hi, is the ParseException an android parse or a java parse?

Comment: import for java parse exception